# CQRS with Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, cqrs

It should be a very quick question. I am trying to learn CQRS pattern and there is one thing which is not clear. There are two dispatchers: for commands and queries. Both of them need to have DI kernel injected in order to get appropriate handler. For example:

```
var handler = _resolver.Resolve<IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>>();
```

Isn't it violating the concept of DI that **Resolve** should never be used and everything should be injected with constructor/properties?

There is a bigger example: http://www.adamtibi.net/06-2013/implementing-a-cqrs-based-architecture-with-mvc-and-document-db

Please check out this method:

```
public void Dispatch<TParameter>(TParameter command) where TParameter : ICommand
{
    var handler = _kernel.Get<ICommandHandler<TParameter>>();
    handler.Execute(command);
}
```

I've found this solution on 3 different pages. Why is it done this way instead of creating a factory to map Query to QueryHandler?

Comment: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/09/19/MessageDispatchingwithoutServiceLocation

Comment: Btw, that's CQS not CQRS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you consider the dispatcher to be a part of the infrastructure, calling Resolve() within it does not violate the DI concept you describe.

Handlers are generally thought of as entry points for logic pipelines (or threads, or however you want to think of them).  This is similar to controllers in MVC, or the Main() method in a console application.  So like these other constructs, the dispatcher is considered a top-level object in the dependency chain, and is thus a perfectly legitimate place to reference the container.

**Edit**

So the comments mention Composition Root (CR), which is a term I like but deliberately tried to avoid in this answer, as it tends to confuse people.  Is the CR a specific class?  An assembly?  I tend to think of it more as a concept than a specific construct.  It's the logical place in the application where object graphs are composed.

To clarify what I meant about controllers: the controllers would be the entry point, and (as @Zbigniew noted) the controller factory would be (part of) the CR.  Similarly, handlers would be the entry point, and the dispatcher would be the CR.  Handlers/Controllers would not have a reference to the container, but the Dispatcher/ControllerFactory would.

Comment: Phil are you suggesting that _handlers_ are [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot) ?

Comment: I am not a web developer but I always thought that any dependencies in MVC are created using ASP.NET MVC factories so container is used inside them not in controllers itself. 
@Michael mentions Composition Root which should be only one inside application and if you use container inside handlers it's hiding all used dependencies in handlers, isn't it wrong?